# Cannot identify source of undefined behaviour in While Loop, Requesting Assistance

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, undefined-behavior

I have a while loop that takes a vector and is supposed to merge intervals. For instance

```
Input: [[2,3],[2,2],[3,3],[1,3],[5,7],[2,2],[4,6]]
Output: [[1,3],[4,7]]
```

Another example:

```
Input: [[1,4],[4,5]]
Output: [[1,5]]
```

I have a snippet of code which finds all the common intervals that lie beside each other, merges them, and then looks at the next element in line:

```
vector<vector<int>> merge(vector<vector<int>>& intervals) {
    sort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), 
         [](vector<int> A, vector<int> B){return A[0] < B[0];});

    int i{};
    while (i++ < intervals.size()) {
        while (intervals.size() >= 2 && intervals[i][1] >= intervals[i+1][0]) {
            intervals[i+1] = {min(intervals[i][0], intervals[i+1][0]),
                              max(intervals[i][1], intervals[i+1][1])};
            intervals.erase(intervals.begin() + i);
        }
        printResult(intervals);
    }
    return intervals;
}
```

The following is my STDOUT:

```
 [1 3 ]
 [4 6 ]
 [5 7 ]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The answer should be

```
[1 3 ]
[4 7 ]
```

but my while loop crashed after the first iteration.

I am not sure why this has been happening and would appreciate if someone can tell me where the problem in my code lies.

Thanks!

Comment: `intervals[i+1]` looks like it will eventually always overflow.

Comment: With `i++ < intervals.size()`, `intervals[i]` can already be out of bound. `intervals[i+1]` is even worse.

Comment: Have you stepped through this with a debugger? Walk through your code until it crashes, and you'll likely be able to determine what happened.

Comment: sometimes i feel really dumb when looking at others code. I think doing everything in place makes the algorithm unnecessarily complicated, can you really not afford to create a temporary? At least taking the parameter as reference **and** returning it is something that needs a fix imho

Comment: @Jarod42 I changed it to i < intervals.size() - 1, with i++ at the bottom of the first loop and it is still crashing like crazy. Any advice?

Comment: @Jarod42 I added a check in the second while loop and now it isn't crashing but also isn't working properly :P

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I made a temp and changed my code.

Comment: First: by using `i++` instead of `++i`, you're changing `i` **after you test it**, which is going to be a problem.  Use `++i`. Secondly, by using intervals[i+1], you're looking one past the current index, which is reading one past the end of you're vector.  Third, you're using a `while` like a `for`.  Just use `for`.

Comment: Instead of `while (i++..` use `for (int = 0; ..; i++)`.

Comment: Also, create a minimal input that exhibits the problem, and then use it to manually walk through the code. You should also reach a point where you would say "this cannot work".